# What is the current fastest algorithm for finding the maximum common subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, graph-isomorphism

First of all, it's my first time at this sub StackExchange so, my apologies if I'm making some newbie mistake when asking this question.

I'm currently researching algorithms for finding the maximum common subgraph isomorphism and after reading a lot of papers I'm still confused about what is the state-of-the-art algorithm for finding the maximum common subgraph between 2 graphs and its computational complexity. Also, all the algorithms I've read about work with 2 graphs (directed or undirected) but none directly work with N graphs. As a note, I've no limitation whatsoever on the kind of graphs and its characteristics.

In summary, my questions are:

- Which is considered the fastest/state-of-the-art algorithm for finding the MCSI? Is it the VF2 algorithm?
- The VF2 algorithm (supposing it's the current state-of-the-art) doesn't work for more than 2 graphs. Any alternate algorithm that works with N graphs where N >= 2?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I have also made this question in [#ComputerScience at StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104706/what-is-the-current-fastest-algorithm-for-finding-the-maximum-common-subgraph). Alas, I haven't had a single answer and thought that perhaps #Mathematics was a more appropriate sub-StackExchange for the question.